# Drop rows from Pandas DF that contain elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a DF:

```
students = [ ('jack', 34, 'Sydeny' , 'Australia') ,
             ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi' , 'India' ) ,
             ('Vikas', 31, 'Mumbai' , 'India' ) ,
             ('Neelu', 32, 'Bangalore' , 'India' ) ,
             ('John', 16, 'New York' , 'US') ,
             ('Mike', 17, 'las vegas' , 'US')  ]

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = ['Name' , 'Age', 'City' , 'Country'], index=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'])
```

And I have a list:

```
[Vikas, Neelu, Jack]
```

How can I drop rows from my DF that contain the elements in this list. My google searches have only shown me how to drop by column indices or conditions like life a column is lower or higher than some integer value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` (not).
- Use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check for containment

```py
remove_words = ['Vikas', 'Neelu', 'Jack']

result = dfObj[~dfObj.Name.isin(remove_words)]

# display(result)

   Name  Age       City    Country
a  jack   34     Sydeny  Australia
b  Riti   30      Delhi      India
e  John   16   New York         US
f  Mike   17  las vegas         US
```

### Ignore Case

- Note that `'Jack'` is not the same as `'jack'`
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) `remove_words` to lowercase (`str.lower`)
- Cast `Name` as lowercase with [`pandas.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) when doing the Boolean check.

  - This will leave the case of the value in the `Name` column, unchanged.

```py
# map the list of words to lowercase
remove_words = list(map(str.lower, ['Vikas', 'Neelu', 'Jack']))

# cast the Name column as lowercase when checking remove_words
result = dfObj[~dfObj.Name.str.lower().isin(remove_words)]

# display(result)
   Name  Age       City Country
b  Riti   30      Delhi   India
e  John   16   New York      US
f  Mike   17  las vegas      US
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `.str.contains` and reverse selection using `~`

```
L=['Vikas', 'Neelu', 'Jack']
dfObj[~dfObj.Name.str.contains('|'.join(L))]



 Name  Age       City    Country
a  jack   34     Sydeny  Australia
b  Riti   30      Delhi      India
e  John   16   New York         US
f  Mike   17  las vegas         US
```